# Calendar Problems

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, calendar, sync

I have a parent and child sites which I need to sync calendars. I

have a master on one site, and I want specific events to be displayed on the child site, but not every event.

I have a column already set up which filters events by this. I do not have access to all of the site, as this is a high-security company, so I cannot create a template. I do need each site to be able to add events, and have it automatically update all calendars linked.

For example:

> Site A is the master and Site B receives events labeled for site B. If
>   someone were to create an event on Site B in their calendar, I need it
>   to also update on Site A.

How do I accomplish this? I have already tried Web parts and content query parts. Content queries did not work, and web parts worked for a while but stopped displaying events.

Comment: Do you need to be able to create an event for Site B from the Site A calendar?

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You could always attach a SharePoint Designer workflow to the master calendar list and inside the workflow you could determine, based on a column or something, whether or not that calendar item should be added to the underlying sub calendars. Inside the workflow logic would be something like:

```
If CurrentItem:Department contains HR
Create List Item in HR Calendar (Copy all the values of it)
else if CurrentItem:Department contains Information Technology
Create List Item in IT Calendar (Copy all the values of it)
```

...
and so on. You can then populate using the content query webpart.

Alternatively, you could use REST calls inside of a 2013 workflow to create items for those lists based on the columns you need for each subsite. Here is how to get started with that (different type of creation, but same principle): https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/08/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-service-from-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: A Designer workflow can't create items in a subsite

Comment: I meant using each of those children calendars inside the same site and exposing it via content query web part in their respective subsites

Comment: That makes sense, but it won't let users update a calendar from Site B.